# ¿Cómo mostrar imagen en el URL y no un string?

Tags: php, laravel, imagen, url

tengo un problema para visualizar mi imagen desde el URL de ella, lo que pasa es que quiero que se muestre la imagen y no un código string, para poder visualizarla de mejor manera.

[image: Este es el problema que tengo]

Entonces claramente quiero que se me muestre la imagen.

Como estoy guardando la imagen:

```
$avatar = $request->file('avatar');
    if($avatar){

        // Poner nombre único
        $avatar_name = 'usuario'.$request->username.'-'.time().$avatar->getClientOriginalName();

        // Guardarla en la carpeta storage (storage/app/users)
        Storage::disk('avatar')->put($avatar_name, File::get($avatar));

        // Seteo el nombre de la imagen en el objeto
        $user->avatar = $avatar_name;
    }
```

Como la obtengo:

```
public function getImage($filename){
    $file = Storage::disk('avatar')->get($filename);
    return new Response($file, 200);
}
```

Ruta para obtener la imagen:

```
Route::get('avatar/{filename}', 'UsuarioController@getImage')->name('user.avatar');
```

Base de datos:

[image: Base de datos]

Mostrando la imagen dentro del blade no tengo problemas.

[image: Imagen mostrada correctamente en el blade]

Comment: public function getImage($filename){
    $file = Storage::disk('avatar')->get($filename);
    return new Response($file, 200);
}

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a añadir el content type del fichero.

```
public function getImage($filename){
    $file = Storage::disk('avatar')->get($filename);
    return new Response($file, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');;

}
```

Comment: Hola, ya lo probé y me da el siguiente error: `syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ';'`

Answer (score 0):

Debes devolver el mimeType en la cabecera de la respuesta para que el navegador lo interprete como una imagen y no un archivo de bites.

Para recogerlo solo tienes que usar la siguiente función.

```
$mime = Storage::mimeType($filename);
```

Y luego simplemente lo devuelves en la petición.

```
return new Response($file, 200)->header('Content-Type', $mime);
```

Comment: Me da este error `syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ';'`

Comment: Prueba con esto 
`return response()->file($pathToFile, $headers);`

Comment: Me sale `File not found at path:`

Answer (score 0):

El `response()` lleva como parámetro el archivo y `mimeType()` la ruta del mismo.

```php
public function getImage($filename) {
    $file = Storage::disk('avatar')->get($filename);
    $path = Storage::disk('avatar')->path($filename);

    return response($file)->header('Content-Type', Storage::disk('avatar')->mimeType($path));
}
```

Comment: Saludos, me sale `File not found at path:`

Comment: Si hacé sun `dd($path)` después de asignar esa variable, que obtenés?

Comment: me sale `"C:\xampp\htdocs\sopita\storage\app/avatar\usuarioAdmin-15694325430f8b2870896edcde8f6149fe2733faaf.jpg"`

Comment: Y esa dirección es correcta? En esa ruta se encuentra ese archivo?